# Paypal Integration in web and app development

Tags: ios, web-services, web, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi Is there any way in iOS or on server end that i can do the payment through paypal without presenting the PayPalPaymentViewController or redirecting the user to paypal. For example if i have the credential of the user of their paypal account than i want if user press the button than the amount will be deducted from the user account. Is this possible through paypal? If yes please tell me. Thanks

Comment: yeah, you can do it. You can create a custom payment view and where you have to pass card number, expiry date to server and server side your PHP guy will make the payments and return message of successfull Payment. Means ALL you have to do it from server side, You have to just pass credentials

Comment: @JeckyModi Do you have some link or tuturiol?

Comment: No, I dont have a tutorial but you can do it like that if you dont want to open paypal screen.

Comment: @JeckyModi I don't want to make the custom view then it's possible?

Comment: Yeah, It's possible. You can to just click on some action to call webservice to pass your credentials like button action. You have to pass just credentials to server and from server side payment is initiated, after success you ask for return message from server.

Comment: Means in simple way, All you have to do it from server side.